# n-bit adder with saturation

Tags: logic, vhdl

Hello there I'm trying to create a n-bit adder/subtractor in VHDL that has a saturation option, if saturation = 1 then if a + b overflows the output vector it should just lock to the maximum value and vice versa for subtraction.

Here's the process for handling the saturation part, I won't post all of my code here for my adder since I know that there is nothing wrong with that part, the problem is my thinking with how to handle the saturation...

```
process(saturate, o_flow, temp_sum)
begin
if (saturate = '1' AND o_flow = '1') then
    if carry(WIDTH-1) = '0' then
        y <= (WIDTH-1 => '0', others => '1');
    else
        y <= (WIDTH-1 => '1', others => '0');
    end if;
else
    y <= temp_sum;
end if;
end process;
```

Would love to get some help, so can you spot my misstake?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious wrong with the code; what problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot `carry` in your sensitivity list:

```
process(saturate, o_flow, temp_sum, carry)
begin
if (saturate = '1' AND o_flow = '1') then
    if carry(WIDTH-1) = '0' then
        y <= (WIDTH-1 => '0', others => '1');
    else
        y <= (WIDTH-1 => '1', others => '0');
    end if;
else
    y <= temp_sum;
end if;
end process;
```

But as you do not really explain what you observe and what is wrong with it, there could be other problems...